# Synchronising Google Calendar to my application in Android

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

I have made a GUI application in Android, to which I would like to sync with Google Calendar.
How could this be done?

Comment: theres a software called erminig for nokia n900 linux , its open source u could srudy the code there or port it to android

Comment: There should be easier way than that, if i know people at google they must have something.

Comment: check this code as its fetching all event from android native calendar and displaying it on a view, as we know the native calendar automatic synced with Google calendar,
http://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2013/05/android-calendar-sync.html

Answer (score 1):

Google has well-documented APIs for its services.  You can find the Calendar API here:

http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html

You might want to also take a look at OAuth as the authentication mechanism, since most users don't like giving out their passwords to apps.  Here's a summary I wrote about OAuth on Android:

http://nilvec.com/implementing-client-side-oauth-on-android.html

Happy hacking!

Comment: @ ldx --> i have gone through that api before and have seen too much stuff in there for  me, could you advise as to what part of the api i should concentrate upon

Comment: If you're okay with just reading calendar entries then take a look at this: http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/reference.html all you need is the metafeed.

Comment: i think i found a good article here http://www.developer.com/ws/article.php/3850276/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar.htm

Comment: @Pallavi Sorry I did not own the link, I guess the original authors removed it - from what I remember is all your app needs is read and write permissions on the google calendar database stored on your phone and then you can just use normal select statements