# how to use google Authorization service in our android application?

Tags: android, google-api

**i am making google calendar application in android and i don't know how to use google Authorization service in our android application?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [project](https://github.com/ddewaele/AndroidOauthGoogleApiJavaClient) describes google auth and this [tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/insert-delete-events-in-android-calendar-t48488.html) for calendar.

Comment: Is there any way to implement google calendar in our application ...i mean by using  GDATA or any other JAR file...

Comment: hello thnx for give me a answer ...here i can get event from google calendar but i can't add event  because for adding event HTTP post require gsessionid parameter and i m not getting to add that parameter ...so plz help me..Thnx

Answer (score 1):

check the OAuth concept in this you can implement by this OAuth.

check this post links

[Android Google Calendar Authorization Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5670517/android-google-calendar-authorization-problem)

[Synchronising Google Calendar to my application in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912269/syncing-google-calendar-to-my-app-in-android)

[Google calendar: how to access it on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452207/google-calendar-how-to-access-it-on-android)

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Android

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("<URL HERE>");

try {

    List<NameValuePair> parameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
    parameters.add(<name_value_pair>);
    parameters.add(<name_value_pair>); 
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));


    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    StatusLine returned_status = response.getStatusLine();
    int status_code = returned_status.getStatusCode();


} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
}
```